# Only counting the cells if the date is greater than another

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[Photo of spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbNp5.png)

I'm looking to the count the cells(months) after a customer first orders or as far back as Apr 2017(column v). I can currently do this when I know the range but I would like it to start on it's own at the first occurrence if it is after Apr 2017. I've included an image to help. For example: if they only been a customer since Feb 2018 I only want to count them as 2 months not since April 2017.

This is my current formula for counting a row that goes back as far as April 2017, =SUM(COUNTIF(V2:AG2,""),(COUNTIF(V2:AG2,">0")))

I have the month of their first order in column AL but I can't seem to get a function working properly where I compare AL to V.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you community.

Comment: What is it about your formula that's not working? Your **Month of First Order** (column AL) seems to agree with the data on each row such that your formula would work. Which row is an example that doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
`=IF(MATCH(TRUE,INDEX((A2:AG2<>0),0),0)<COLUMN(V2),COLUMN(AG2)-COLUMN(V2)+1,COLUMN(AG2)-MATCH(TRUE,INDEX((A2:AG2<>0),0),0)+1)`

This says that if the first non-blank cell in A2:AG2 is before V2 then give the number of months between V2 & AG2, otherwise, count the number of months between the first non-blank cell after column V and column AG.

I used the COLUMN function in case you want to make changes to the periods you're looking at later.  LMK if this works for you.

Comment: What you are describing in your description sounds right but it keeps giving me a value of "12" for each row.

Comment: Do you have information in column A? If so, try changing the index array to B2:AG2 instead.

Comment: Solved, thank you for your help. I had to remove the +1 because it was skewing the data a bit.  I can use this on many applications now. Could you just explain what the 0 placeholders constitute in MATCH(TRUE,INDEX((A2:AG2<>0),0),0) ? Thanks again

Comment: For INDEX, the zero at the end indicates the row number, which is required for the formula; tbh, I'm not exactly sure why it needs to be 0 for this to work, but I believe it has something to do with the fact that there's only one row in the array it's searching. For MATCH, the final zero defines the match type, which is `exact` in this case. Other types are: `1 - less than` and `-1 - greater than`

Comment: Right on, I've never quite understood that either but it's a ton of my formulas so just thought I'd ask. Thank you again.

Comment: Sure thing, happy to help.  If you don't mind marking my response as the answer, I would appreciate it.  Thanks!